# Quality-loss by resampling an image bigger?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize, resolution, image-quality

If you have an image you want to make bigger(in realife-size for example for printing), I would use the crop tool of Photoshop with WxHxResolution, use centimeters/inches and then set my ppi.

My question is, wether this approach is right and how strong the quality loss then will be, especially when also setting a higher ppi?

Comment: ok that's right, but what about my approach?

Comment: I don't know why you would ever use the crop tool to upscale an image.  You should use the Image Size window for resizing images...cropping and resizing are not the same, hence the separate tools.